# xml with xsl different output with links

Tags: html, xml, xslt, hyperlink

I want to use my xml file to create different xsl pages.

i.e

```
    <movies>
      <movie>
        <name>Shark tank</name>
      <movie>
      <movie>
        <name>Tank Shark</name>
      <movie>
   <movies>
```

I want to display this information using xsl however i want the first movie on it's on page with a link to another page displaying movie2. Is this possible and if so how do i go about getting my desired outcome ?

Comment: You need to two xsl files for this.

Comment: Yeah but how do I link them ? To create two different pages. I have an xsl created both of the pages I want displayed. But I don't know how to create a link from one xsl page to another.

Answer (score 0):

On the main page you're going to want something like this at the beginning of the main.xsl file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
    version="1.0" xml:lang="en"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
>
<xsl:import href="./file1.xsl"/>
<xsl:import href="./file2.xsl"/>
```

Unless you are using all xml file with one main xsl file, then add these global variables example after the imports:

```
<xsl:variable name="MOVIE" select="document('movies.xml')"/>
```

with that you can call these variables as such:

```
<a href="http://iheartsharks.com">
    <xsl:value-of select="$MOVIE/movie[name = "'Shark tank']"/>
</a>
```